# Flex application layers

Tags: apache-flex, components, tiers

I'm new to Flex and I want to separate app tiers/components as much as possible.

So I have three mxmls:

1. `X.mxml` which has a datagrid with
   students
2. `Y.mxml` which must be able
   to tell which student is selected in
   the X.mxml's datagrid (row id ?)
3. `XY.mxml` which uses the previous 2

Which is the best practice here ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this I use an MVC framework, specifically [Robotlegs](http://robotlegs.org). Robotlegs is simple to use and allows you to create mediators for your components. [Here is a video](http://joelhooks.com/2009/11/11/a-walkthrough-of-an-air-twitter-client-using-robotlegs-mvcs/) I recorded going through some simple steps for wiring an application.

That said, your components can communication via XY. Y will have a public property called `selectedStudent` which can be bound to the `selectedItem` property of X:

```
<Y selectedStudent="{X.dataGrid.selectedItem}"/>
```

So, when the selected item is updated, it updates the selected student property.

Comment: Joel, I have 2 mxml files(rateNav.mxml and addBrs.mxml) I'm calling addBrs via popupmanager both of which are TitleWindows. How do I call members/fields that are within rateNav from addBrs?